# rails: is there a way to include multiple link_to's in yml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, yaml, erb, link-to

I would like to clean up my views a little bit. Currently I am not sure about the syntax of yml and if there is a way to include link_to methods in a yml statement. One solution without link_to methods is the following, but I would like to keep it more simple if there is a way to do so. I don't like putting my css classes and other link params in the yml file. Since I'm quiet new to ruby on rails, I'm not sure if there is a smarter solution than that.

erb:

```
<%= raw(t('registration.terms')) %>
```

yml:

```
en:
  registration:
    terms: |
        <label for="registration_terms">I accept the</label> <a href='#terms_of_service' class='simple_link' rel='facebox'>Terms of Services</a> 
        <label for="registration_terms">and the</label> <a href='/non/i18n/supported/path' class='simple_link' rel='facebox'>Terms of Privacy</a> <label for="registration_terms">...</label>.
```

Comment: the yml file is for localization only, meaning only put the text there and not any code to generate its link

Comment: I know, but what do you do if you have a text with links included? I don't want to split up my text in several parts, that doesn't makes much sense to me, because in another language is the link position in the text somewhere else or the structure of the sentence is different

Comment: store the link location rather than the link its self

Comment: I have the same problem. How do you solve this?
I always get:
"Email has been taken. You can <a href='/recover_password'>recover</a> your password."

Comment: @LeoGasparrini as far as I remember it made at the end more sense to pass in a variable with the link location/url.